# How can I make a matplotlib pdf without a clipping bounding box?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

My usual workflow is to generate a plot using matplotlib, save the plot as a pdf using `savefig()`, and then open the plot in Adobe Illustrator to do final tweaking.  Every pdf created by matplotlib has a clipping mask around the border of the content.  I find it quite annoying to always release the clipping mask and then delete the clipping bounding box before I begin adjusting my pdf.  Is there some way to eliminate this clipping behavior?

To make this more concrete, here is an example,

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot([0,1], [0,1])
plt.savefig('Test.pdf')
```

which creates a pdf with a clipping mask around the outside edges, even though there is nothing to clip.

I noticed that I can set `fig.set_clip_on=False`, but it does not do anything.  In fact, if I set `fig.set_clip_on=False` and directly afterwards query `fig.get_clip_on`, it returns `True`.

Any suggestions to get rid of the clipping bbox?

Comment: On problem is that `set_clip_on` is a function, not an attribute, so assigning `True` to at at best has no effect, and may raise strange errors later.

Comment: I just created a feature request on Github (Issue #2528) asking the developers to allow the user to turn off the clipping bbox.